# .NET Core publish and version errors

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, publish

I'm hunting an error message and unclear behaviour with a .NET Core app and self-contained publishing. I've just installed .NET Core 2.2.3 SDK and created a simple console app called `CoreVerTest` with Visual Studio 2017 (15.9). Everything is okay to this point. It says "Hello World!" when I run it.

Then I proceed to the build script that creates self-contained versions. Here's the script, `build.cmd` in the project's directory (where .csproj is):

```
@echo off
set TargetFramework=netcoreapp2.2

:: Clean
if exist bin\Release\%TargetFramework% rd /s /q bin\Release\%TargetFramework% || goto error
dotnet clean -v m -c Release -nologo || goto error

:: Build
powershell write-host -fore Blue Building and publishing...
dotnet publish -c Release -nologo || goto error

powershell write-host -fore Blue Publishing for win-x64...
dotnet publish -c Release -r win-x64 -nologo || goto error

powershell write-host -fore Blue Publishing for linux-arm...
dotnet publish -c Release -r linux-arm -nologo || goto error

:: Exit
powershell write-host -fore Green Build finished.
timeout /t 2 /nobreak >nul
exit /b

:error
pause
```

This cleans everything and then does

- a normal Release build, framework-dependent
- a self-contained Release build and publish for Windows x64
- a self-contained Release build and publish for Linux ARM (my primary target platform)

I have not touched the .csproj file at all, it's all defaults.

There are a number of issues with this:

1. After running build.cmd while the project is open in Visual Studio, VS shows me this error message:

   > Error NETSDK1061: Das Projekt wurde mit Microsoft.NETCore.App, Version 2.2.3 wiederhergestellt, aber mit den aktuellen Einstellungen würde stattdessen Version 2.2.0 verwendet werden. Um dieses Problem zu beheben, müssen Sie sicherstellen, dass für die Wiederherstellung und für nachfolgende Vorgänge wie das Kompilieren oder Veröffentlichen dieselben Einstellungen verwendet werden. Dieses Problem tritt typischerweise auf, wenn die RuntimeIdentifier-Eigenschaft bei der Kompilierung oder Veröffentlichung, aber nicht bei der Wiederherstellung festgelegt wird. Weitere Informationen finden Sie unter https://aka.ms/dotnet-runtime-patch-selection.

   The error goes away after a rebuild solution or VS restart. It does not go away when running the clean part again.
2. It is unclear what version of .NET Core was packaged. I can't find any DLL in the publish directory that gives me the version 2.2.3, everything's got funny random numbers like 4.6 or 10.0. From another more complex project, I have the impression that the roll-forward is not performed and .NET Core 2.2.0 is instead published. I have no way to verify that.
3. [This page](https://techblog.dorogin.com/how-to-detect-net-core-version-in-runtime-ecd65ad695be) shows how to query the framework runtime version at runtime. It shows 2.2.3 when I run it from Visual Studio but is empty when I run a self-contained app. So this doesn't work for self-contained apps.

How can I get rid of the error message in Visual Studio and verify that all versions are correct (expect the framework-dependent app to target 2.2.0 and run on 2.2.3 if installed; expect the self-contained app to include the bits of 2.2.3 only)?

(I've reported the error message elsewhere already but can't find where that was. There was no solution either.)

Answer (score 0):

Editing to handle both scenarios.

Try setting RuntimeFrameworkVersion using condition on RuntimeIdentifier:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(RuntimeIdentifier)' == 'win-x64'">
    <RuntimeFrameworkVersion>2.2.2</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(RuntimeIdentifier)' == 'linux-arm'">
    <RuntimeFrameworkVersion>2.2.2</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Note: Above I have set RuntimeFrameworkVersion to 2.2.2 just to verify that self contained publish does not just pick up the latest version installed on my system. You can set it to your required version.

After the build you should see:

1. Self contained deployments have their .deps.json file mention 2.2.2 for Microsoft.NETCore.App. Their runtimeconfig.json would be empty.
2. The framework dependent one has runtimeconfig.json with version 2.2.0 and will therefore pickup any 2.2.* installed on the system.

Comment: Does that mean that the framework-dependent app will only run if at least 2.2.3 is installed? This would be not recommended. It should work if at least 2.2.0 is installed but use the latest installed runtime.